# cant connect to ipfs external node on infura.io via curl

Tags: web3js, infura, ipfs

im trying to to store data to ipfs via php , i use curl to communicate with api , it works find on my local node , but i want to use external node from infura.io

but for some reason ipfs.infura.io is refusing my connection via php
even a simple command like ... i've tried it on my localhost as well as couple of servers

here is a simple endpoint which you can open in the browser and get the output

> https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/pin/add?arg=QmeGAVddnBSnKc1DLE7DLV9uuTqo5F7QbaveTjr45JUdQn

but when i try to open it via php i get

> Failed to connect to ipfs.infura. io port 5001: Connection refused

or when using another method like file_get_contents

> file_get_contents(ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/pin/add?arg=QmeGAVddnBSnKc1DLE7DLV9uuTqo5F7QbaveTjr45JUdQn): failed to open stream: Connection refused

i've tried it on local host and  multiple server , i get the same result even via ssh command line
[image]

[image]

any idea why is this happening ?

here is a simplified version n of my code

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/pin/add?arg=QmeGAVddnBSnKc1DLE7DLV9uuTqo5F7QbaveTjr45JUdQn");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    $res = curl_exec($curl);
    if (curl_errno($curl)) {
        $error_msg = curl_error($curl);
        echo ('error ...');
        echo ($error_msg);
       exit();
    }

    curl_close($curl);
    echo($res);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. I also can get correct response with curl.
I think you should search the reason of your problem in your network infrastructure. Here is https://stackoverflow.com/a/2333446/7581809 good discussion why this problem can happen.
You said you tryed different servers. Are these servers in same network ? May be there is a firewall in this network, which rejects your packets to infura. Try another server from another network.

Comment: yep still not sure what the problem is , but trying it on different server worked

Comment: This seems to be a simple networking problem, probably port 5001 is blocked as an external port in your local firewall/proxy/remote firewall/router. This is common if you use a network inside a company. If curl works somewhere else, it means it is a networking issue.

Comment: @GiuseppeBertone if we send request to endpoint on port 5001 .... we still use our 80 port to send the request aren't we ?

Comment: @max No, we are not. When you open TCP connection one of ephemeral ports is used on client side for outgoing connection. If you have 80 port used by some process (your http server for example) nothing else can use this port.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port